# EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean dosenot create bean for JPARepositories

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-envers, spring-data-envers

I am using spring boot, hibernate enverse. I have following dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-envers</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

following is my envers config.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = 
EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean.class, basePackages = { 
"com.example.persistence" })
public class EnversConf
{

}
```

So package `com.example.persistence` have `PersonDAO` and `AddressDAO` and also Entities.

I have following two DAOs,

```
interface PersonDAO  extends RevisionRepository<PersonEntity, Integer, Integer>, JpaRepository<PersonEntity, Integer>{}

interface AddressDAO  extends JpaRepository<AddressEntity, Integer>{}
```

I have two entities `PersonEntity` which I want to audit and `AddressEntity` which I don't want to audit.

Now I have following two services,

```
class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService{
    @Autowire PersonDAO personDAO;
}

class AddressServiceImpl implements AddressService{
    @Autowire AddressDAO addressDAO;
}
```

When I add `@EnableJpaRepositories(...)` config it unable to get beans for `AddressDAO`. I thought `EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean` works for both `RevisionRepository` and `JpaRepository`.

I got following exception stacktrace,

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'addressService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'addressDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'addressDAO': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAll found for type AddressEntity!
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'addressDAO': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAll found for type AddressEntity!
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAll found for type AdressEntity!

Am I missing any configuration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got solution ;)

Need to create two separate configuration classes as we cannot use TWO @EnableJpaRepositories on same configuration class.

So have created following two configuration classes,

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.jpa.dao")
class JpaConfig {}

@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean, basePackages = "com.example.envers.dao")
class EnversConfig {}
```